# how to know what port is used to make http Get request from Postman

Tags: http, postman

how to know what port is used to make http Get request from Postman?

I made this http Get request for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

This request got through to the destination and the client could get response.

Comment: 3000 ! is the port you just mentioned it in the url

Comment: 3000 is the part number of destination, right? I want to know the port from which the request is sent.

Comment: you can check local address

Comment: See the updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can goto **console >network >remote address to know the IP and port of the destination**

if you goto localaddress , it shows the network through which it will connect to the destination (Meaning the subnet network ) like wireless network , vlan network etc.

### You can goto cmd and type ifconfig or ipconfig and verify this